# Refresh php function in div without page reload?

Tags: javascript, php

I've made a more simple ping statues system for my servers.
Right now my PHP function does a simple fsockopen and show Green/Red echo if up/down.

This ping status is only shown when the site is loaded.

Question : **Can I somehow refresh and execute the function again without the whole page reload?
I mean to have live status of servers changing if it goes down, without reloading the whole page.**

```
<?php

function pingstate($host, $port) {

  if (!$socket = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 0.1)){
    echo "<p class='pingRed'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i></p>";
  } else {
    echo "<p class='pingGreen'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i></p>";
    fclose($socket);
  }
}
 ?>
```

Example of output I use on other page than the function.
This part works great but I have to "reload" the page everytime I want new status of the ping.

```
$host = $row['host'];
$port = 80;
            echo "<tr>
              <td>" .$row['eq']."</td>
              <td>".$row['ChargePoint']."</td>
              <td>".$row['ip_addres']."</td>
              <td>".$row['host']."</td>
              <td><i class='fa fa-dashboard'></i></td>
              <td><a href='http://".$row['host']."/' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-gear'></i></a></td>
                            <td>";
                            echo pingstate($host, $port);
                            echo "</td></tr>";
```

I was thinking of maybe JavaScript that reloads the table row?
How can this be done, I googled but cannot find for reload functions..

Please help me with explanation, I really want to learn.

Thank you!

Comment: AJAX is your friend for this, I'll provide you a solution :)

Comment: Check out my snippet and try to implement it for you.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: its real bad coding style to use PHP to echo html. You should avoid it if possible.

My structure would look like this:

create a file called server_check.php and use your checking code inside like this:

```
  if (!$socket = @fsockopen($_GET["HOST"], $_GET["PORT"], $errno, $errstr, 0.1)){
    echo json_encode("offline");
    die;
  } else {
    echo json_encode("online");
    fclose($socket);
    die;       }
  echo json_encode("no ping possible");
```

Next step is to create a html file with the following content. I'm using jQuery for simplifying your problem. You may use vanilla javascript if you prefer that.

```js
let server_list = {
  "example.com": 111,
  "example1.com": 111
};

function checkServer() {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "server_check.php",
      data: {
        HOST: key,
        PORT: value
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#'+key).text(data);
    });
  }

}

setInterval(checkServer, 10000); //Checks server each 10 secs
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous"> Info about Server EXAMPLE.COM Server is
<p id="example.com">NOT CHECKED</p>

Server EXAMPLE1.COM Server is
<p id="example1.com">NOT CHECKED</p>
```

EDIT: Please be aware of several security issues and non existent error handling. Please read on several topics (GET/POST/HTTP requests) and ajax in general before using this in a productive environment. If you have further questions feel free to ask them right away.

Comment: Hello, very nice script, one question tho :P
I have not only one pingstate to check and not only 1 port.

Today its like 10 different services with 10 different ports.
The array I spit out from the DB is determing the hostname. The port is set by hand as you can see. How can I make this possible? The function I have above is already in a other .php file.

Comment: I cannot use it in the GET function since the ping statues is 10+ servers on same page.
https://imgur.com/a/eswgsiH

Comment: Now you can add server and its port in a key : value syntax and the loop will iterate over it. If my answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: How can I contact you for more information. I want to share stuff that cannot be written publicaly. Thank you